# Pass data from one form to another on same page before submit

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

I have two forms on one page.
In my first form I have all the field data (name, username, password, etc). In my second form I just have a button. Both forms on submission go to different actions in my controller.

***Problem*** - when I submit form 2 from buton click, any fields from form 1 don't get passed to the controller via ViewModel. Ex. The action "ExternalLogin" doesn't get the "Gender" field value

How can I pass "Gender" from the first form to my second form before I submit the second form? JQuery? I tried putting HTML.HiddenFor(m => m.Gender) in my second form, but that didn't work.

Here is some sample code.

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", @id = "registerForm", role = "form", style = "margin-left: 20px" })) 
{
    <div id="formGroup1" class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Gender, new { @id = "genderLabel" })
        <div class="">
        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, new {@id = "genderId", @class = "selectpicker form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    // other fields here
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLogin", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { ReturnUrl = Model.ReturnUrl, @id = "registerForm", role = "form", style = "margin-left: 20px" })) 
{
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="facebookButton" name="provider" value="Facebook" title="Log in using your Facebook account" style="width: 280px; color: white; background-color: #4c7bd9"><i class="fa fa-facebook" style="color: white"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Connect</button>
}
```

Comment: Do not use 2 forms. Use one form with 2 buttons with the same `name` attribute and different `value` attributes. Then post to one method with a parameter from the button name and perform your logic based on the clicked button

Comment: I don't think this will work because I'm doing lots of validation on the first form, and the second form needs no validation. If I have two buttons in 1 form regardless of which button I pres I'll still have to validate all teh fields. All I need in the second form is 1 enum value from the first.

Comment: Well that's not what you question indicates :). Then you need to include a hidden input in the second form and handle the second submit button to get the value(s) from the first form and update the inputs in the 2nd form.

Comment: I was thinking I could create a hidden field in the second form and on enum onChange() in the first form I can set the hidden value in teh second form?

Comment: Yes, that's another option

Comment: @user1186050 as you said and I quote "Singe button will submit data to two actions " am I right? second please tell what is nature of second form I expect its a "Partail", and are both the forms using different model?

Comment: @user1186050 Please check the answer and if it meets your needs upvote and mark as answer

Comment: @user1186050 Excuse Me I spent more than half an hour answering your question yesterday please see the answer and if it is good enough mark it as an answer and upvote please

Answer (score 0):

This Works Perfectly and does what you want

Controller Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Temp.Models;

namespace Temp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public void Register(MyModel mymodel)
        {

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public void ExternalLogin(int mygender)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Model Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Temp.Models
{
    public class MyModel
    {
        public enum Gender { Male = 1, Female = 2 }

        public Gender gender { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View Code

```
@model Temp.Models.MyModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnChange()
    {
        $("#mygender").val($("#genderId").val())    
    }

</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", @id = "registerForm", role = "form", style = "margin-left: 20px" }))
{
    <div id="formGroup1" class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.gender, new { @id = "genderLabel" })
        <div class="">
            @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.gender, new { @id = "genderId", @class = "selectpicker form-control",@onchange="javascript:OnChange();" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Connect</button>

}

@using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLogin", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "registerForm", role = "form", style = "margin-left: 20px" }))
{
    <input type="hidden" id="mygender" name="mygender"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Connect</button>
}
```